# Digitizing BW artwork at highest possible resolution

Tags: scanning, digitizing

I have an artwork - black ink on paper (a4 size), with a lot of details, thin lines. The quality of the artwork is good.

I have a cheap scanner and a cheap camera. With the scanner results are very poor. I have tried it on another scanner at work. Still the results are not good enough  - with my eyes I see much more detail and the contours in the scanned image are partially destroyed, which is not acceptable. I am an experienced user, so it is not that I don't know how to setup the scanner, I have tried different setups, but still I am not satisfied.

Then I have tried it with my (cheap) camera. Interestingly in some sense the results were slightly better, namely the lighting generally preserves better, but there are problems with focusing (it has semiautomatic focusing).

My Task:

I need only binary information, but with highest possible detail, perfectly I must be able to see ink diffusion structure on the resulting image. All the information must be preseved as it is. But I am **not** interested in geometry deformation on the periphery, I can make many fotos of all regions of interest, so I could use a camera also.

#### Question

Should I look for a scanner or a special camera for this task? I cannot buy it, but I could at least search for a camera rent service for example. At this moment I want to know which way to go in general - a camera or a scanner or something else.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to realize the details of reality. You can plug in other numbers, but consider the numbers. Suppose you used a 24 megapixel DSLR camera.  It has an image size of 6000x4000 pixels.  Photographing an A4 artwork, (8.27 x 11.69 inches), the maximum resolution will be 4000 pixels / 8.27 inches = 484 dpi result. Which is a lot, but the camera cannot do more (not and still see full page).

Implying that a scanner at 1200 or 2400 dpi will run circles around it, resolution-wise.  The 1200 dpi image of A4 will be
(8.27 x 1200 dpi) x (11.69 x 1200 dpi) = 9924 x 14028 pixels.
More than twice larger than 4000x6000 pixels. Twice as much detail.

I am NOT knocking the digital camera for reproducing like 35mm slides. They can do this great (with a macro lens).  However, A4 is much larger, and camera sensors are a little small.

Lens quality can be an issue, but it is not a difficult job. Assuming gear of reasonable quality, either scanner or camera should be adequate.

You said cheap scanner results were poor.  You gave no details, causing me to suspect that scanner is adequate, and that maybe you were using scanner color mode? (inappropriate for ink line drawings). Experienced users will know the details, and know why the details.

Scanners have three modes:  **Color, grayscale, and line art mode** (all of which could have different names, but there are only these three same modes).

So instead (for black ink lines), use only line art mode, which might be named B&W mode, or maybe text document mode, but it is the third mode that is Not Color and is Not Grayscale.  Lineart is only two colors, black or white... no gray (like your ink work).  Scan line art at least at 600 dpi, maybe 1200 dpi. A camera sensor is necessarily color mode, no line art capability.

It is not totally impossible that your black ink could show some gray tones, like if ink in a spot was spread thin, instead of thick ink.  Lineart will NOT pick up that difference, and if it is actually an important factor, then you need grayscale scan mode, and then lower resolution will do, 300 dpi or 600 dpi.  The difference is in how printers with only black ink must simulate that gray shade with several dots.

And you have to reason your goal for such resolution.  Reproduction is all that comes to my mind.  High scan resolution is not actually for detail, instead it is for enlarged reproduction.  The idea is that to print 2x original size copies, we scan at 2x the desired printing resolution goal (scan at 600 dpi, print at 300 dpi, which will reproduce at 2x size).

I am saying 300 dpi... color needs about 300 dpi, but artwork of black ink lines will need 600 dpi, or maybe 1200 dpi to reproduce in the best degree, but you also will require a printing process than can provide that much resolution.